# show paragraph on image mouseover

Tags: jquery, hover, onmouseover

I have images in divs and I would like to have paragraphs to appear on top of them on mouseover, using jQuery. The paragraphs are initially hidden.

I've tried the following but can't make the paragraph to appear only when I mouseover one image, on top of that image only.

HTML:

```
<div id="photos">

    <div class="test">
        <img src="http://www.blset.com/img/300x200/biostat300200.jpg" />
        <p class="desc">Test 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="test">
        <img src="http://www.blset.com/img/300x200/barometre1300200.jpg" />
        <p class="desc">Test 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#photos {position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background:#ccc;}

#photos img {float:left;height:120px;}

#photos p {display:none; position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".test img").hover(function() {

        $(".test p").fadeIn(200);
    }, function () {

        $(".test p").fadeOut(200);

    });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7zFb/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".test img").hover(function(e) {
    $(e.target).next().fadeIn(200);
}, function (e) {
    $(e.target).next().fadeOut(200);
});
```

with the following CSS:

```
.test { float: left;position: relative; }

#photos {position:relative;}

#photos img {height:120px;}

#photos p {display:none; position:absolute;top:0;left:;}
```

jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/m7zFb/15/

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick. I'm now going to read more about next() and e.target.

Comment: Sure thing - one more note, you can use `$(this)` instead for `$(e.target)` - I'm just used to using `e.target`...

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have a problem because block elements like P don't get contained in DIV elements when setup in this fashion.  Also, you have your P elements set for absolute positioning but haven't defined your containing elements positioning.  So, your P ends up positioning relative to the viewport.

Personally, if you want the text to be on top of the image and make it a bit simpler: I would make the place the images as the background for the div's such that background-image: url('imagepath');  Then you can plop your text right in there, without P element tags unless you really need them, since you can specify in the CSS the text positioning for the DIV itself without impacting the IMG element.

If you want more information on the positioning and floating and block elements, this is a good tutorial on the topic: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/.  Remember, always set the width and height if you are going to float elements.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment @matthewnreid, I'll go and read some more about it.